# How to import a SAS layout or Data Dictionary

Tags: government, medical, conversion

Being totally new to SAS, I don't know how to import this layout/dictionary file into SAS® Studio:

```
       *********************************************
       *                                           *
       *           A T T E N T I O N               *
       *                                           *
       *   THESE POS RECORD SPECIFICATIONS WERE    *
       *   PRODUCED FROM OUR DICTIONARY AT THE     *
       *   SAME TIME AS THE POS DATA FILE THAT     *
       *   YOU REQUESTED. YOU MAY WISH TO CHECK    *
       *   THESE SPECIFICATIONS TO SEE IF ANY      *
       *   CHANGES HAVE OCCURED SINCE YOUR RECEIPT *
       *   OF ANY PRIOR DOCUMENTATION.             *
       *                                           *
       *   FILE CREATION DATE = 01/02/2018         *
       *                                           *
       *********************************************
 DATE: 01/02/2018              POS RECORD LAYOUT                      PAGE: 1
                 Hospital, CATEGORY = "01" (SEE POSITIONS 3-4)

   SHORT DESCRIPTION                                LEN  START END    TYPE

   Provider Category Subtype Code                    2    1     2    VARCHAR2
     Description: Identifies the subtype of the provider, within the
                  primary category.  Used in reporting to show the
                  breakdown of provider categories, mainly for hospitals
                  and SNFs.
     SAS Name:    PRVDR_CTGRY_SBTYP_CD
     COBOL Name:  PRVDR-CTGRY-SBTYP-CD
     VALUES:      01=Short Term
                  02=Long Term
                  ....
```

I got this file from [cms.gov](https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Downloadable-Public-Use-Files/Provider-of-Services/index.html) and I want to convert/export the data inside this text file into a MySQL database but first how can I import this into SAS Studio (ex. [SAS University Edition](https://www.sas.com/en_us/software/university-edition/download-software.html))?

I was expecting that the provided data dictionary text file can be easily opened/imported into a SAS software but it seems not an easy task accoring to this reply from a [communities.sas.com](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Studio/How-to-import-a-SAS-layout-or-Data-Dictionary/m-p/427972#M4326) user.

I have no knowledge at all in SAS and I am not willing to learn it as this is just a one time import/conversion. All what I want to know (from SAS oriented users) is how they convert this kind of dictionary data into something that can be exported to work with in my PHP/MySQL world.

I tried to parse the txt file in PHP and extract the different columns for each table (18 tables) but still have some issue since the file format is not consistent.

The data I want to extract is explained in my [stackoverflow.com question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473193/php-regex-parse-data-from-complex-text-file)

[image]

Comment: sas isn't open...but since you are trying to convert out of it, this question is applicable here.